# PHP largest and smallest number given to a form

Tags: php

Can any body suggest a good PHP function which help me do the smallest and largest of a user input arrays. I searched for almost an hour but I couldn't come up with any valuable function which can help me do the following assignment.
**Assignment:**
The below PHP script prints the largest and smallest number given to a form. Your task is to write the missing functions (largest and smallest), that receive the integers given by user as parameters and then return the largest and smallest integers. Incomplete program:

```
<?php
    $first = $_GET['first'];
    $second = $_GET['second'];
    $third = $_GET['third'];         

    //Your code here

    $largest_number = largest($first, $second, $third);
    $smallest_number = smallest($first, $second, $third);    

    echo "From the numbers you typed, the largest was $largest_number";
    echo " and smallest $smallest_number";    
?>
```

`Example output`

> From the numbers you typed, the largest was 10 and smallest -1

Comment: How about $largest_number = max($first, $second, $third); $smallest_number = min($first, $second, $third); Or do you need logic behind it

Comment: Hi, I am supposed to complete the missing code in the middle where it says "// your code here." So I need a function which would match with the rest of the code.

Comment: Ha, okay yeah these are built into PHP

Comment: do you have just three values which you get ?

Comment: Hi, my hope is each gets one value but I am not sure about that.

Comment: I just posted the full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for any amount of parameters

```
<?php

foreach($_GET as $a_parameter)
{

if($a_parameter==intval($a_parameter))   // only if parameter is a number
{
    if(!isset($minimum)) // for the first time paremeter is minimum
    {
        $minimum = $a_parameter;
    }

    if(!isset($maximum)) // for the first time paremeter is maximum
    {
        $maximum= $a_parameter;
    }

    if($a_parameter<$minimum)  // for each parameter we check if its lower and set minimum
    {
        $minimum=$a_parameter;
    }

    if($a_parameter>$maximum) // for each parameter we check if its greater and set maximum
    {
        $maximum=$a_parameter;
    }


}

echo "From the numbers you typed, the largest was ".$maximum." and smallest ".$minimum;

?>
```

edit: i made some typos, just corrected them now its ok -i added some comments also

**update: i just realized this answer is not in the form you asked for** "*Your task is to write the missing functions (largest and smallest), that receive the integers given by user as parameters and then return the largest and smallest integers.*"

anyway i won't delete the answer i will leave it here if anybody wanna take a look since it answers the question as described in your title *"PHP largest and smallest number given to a form"* maybe it will be helpfull to a google visitor :D

***UPDATE 2: I decided to change the code a bit so it actually answers your question, here it is:***

```
<?php
$first = 34; //$_GET['first'];
$second = -55; //$_GET['second'];
$third = 90; //$_GET['third'];         

//Your code here




function smallest($first, $second, $third)
{
    foreach(func_get_args() as $a_parameter)
    {

        if($a_parameter==intval($a_parameter))   // only if parameter is a number
        {

            if(!isset($minimum)) // for the first time paremeter is maximum
            {
                $minimum= $a_parameter;
            }

            if($a_parameter<$minimum)  // for each parameter we check if its lower and set minimum
            {
                $minimum=$a_parameter;
            }
        }

    }
    return $minimum;
}


function largest($first, $second, $third)
{
    foreach(func_get_args() as $a_parameter)
    {

        if($a_parameter==intval($a_parameter))   // only if parameter is a number
        {
            if(!isset($maximum)) // for the first time paremeter is maximum
            {
                $maximum= $a_parameter;
            }

            if($a_parameter>$maximum) // for each parameter we check if its greater and set maximum
            {
                $maximum=$a_parameter;
            }
        }
    }
    return $maximum;
}


$largest_number = largest($first, $second, $third);
$smallest_number = smallest($first, $second, $third); 

echo "From the numbers you typed, the largest was $largest_number";
echo " and smallest $smallest_number";    

?>
```

working demo here

http://3v4l.org/Qh0YA

Answer (score 1):

```
$smallest = min ( array(2, 4, 5)  )// prints 2
$largest = max ( array(2, 4, 5)  )// prints 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some logic if you want to go that route

```
<?php
$first = $_GET['first'];
$second = $_GET['second'];
$third = $_GET['third'];  
$numbers = array($first, $second, $third); 
 function largest($array)
{
   $largest = $array[0];
   foreach($array as $value)
   {

    if($value > $largest)
    {

    $largest = $value;
    }

  }

    return $largest;    
}
function smallest($array)
{
   $smallest = $array[0];
   foreach($array as $value)
   {

    if($value < $smallest)
    {

    $smallest = $value;
    }

  }

    return $smallest;   
}      

$largest_number = largest($numbers);
$smallest_number = smallest($numbers);    

echo "From the numbers you typed, the largest was $largest_number";
echo " and smallest $smallest_number";    
?>
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks, I am 100% sure this is homework.. in the real world we would just use the functions provided in the language!